# How to split specific string by delimiter

Tags: javascript

i am having problems with splitting string with this name inside:
Aix-en-Provence

String possibilities are:

Aix-en-Provence-Test2
Test2-Aix-en-Provence

I would like to split string dynamically with delmiter ('-') to get Aix-en-Provence and Test2 seperated.

How to? I was trying with Regex.execute with different patterns but unsuccessful. I am parsing data in Javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards

Comment: To do that, you have to have some advance knowledge other than that you're using a `-`, e.g., that "Aix-en-Provence" (or "Test2") is special. Do you have that advance knowledge available to your code? Because if not, you can't do this.

Comment: Depends on what your strings can be. Maybe a regex could help: `input.split(/-(?!en|Provence)/);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
function mySplit(myString, splitString, protectString){
    var specialString = 'somespecialchar';
    var r = new RegExp('(^|-)('+protectString+')(-|$)');
    var a = myString.replace(r, '$1'+specialString+'$3').split('-');
    a.forEach(function(e, i, a){
        if (e == specialString) a[i] = protectString;
    });
    return a;
}
mySplit('Aix-en-Provence-Test2', '-', 'Aix-en-Provence');
mySplit('Test2-Aix-en-Provence', '-', 'Aix-en-Provence');
```

The function is far from perfect, you should escape regex special chars from `"protectString"` but it does the job for your strings.